# how to pass curl -d parameters in postman request

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, curl, postman

Here what I am trying to do is , I am trying to pass

```
curl -X GET \
  -d 'access_token=<ACCESS_TOKEN>' \
```

into the request, but somehow I am unable to find the equivalent field in the postman where I can fill these details.

Comment: Is it because it’s a GET request and Postman doesn’t show the `body` option? If you we’re to switch to a POST method you would now be able to access that part of the tool. That doesn’t help but that’s probably why you don’t see an option. Could it maybe a header or URL param instead?

Comment: it is get request from API side. So, how to pass these `d` fields in postman?

Comment: I don’t think the option to add request body data to a GET request is something that Postman currently handles. Looking at some of the projects discussions on GitHub seems to confirm this too.

Comment: but , isn't . `-F ` supposed to be the body type of request ?

Comment: Yes but if you open the application and try to construct a GET request, you will see that the body section on the request body is not accessible

Comment: Then is there any other tool through which this is possible?

Comment: Possibly https://insomnia.rest/ or curl I guess :)